# How to set text XAlign to left regardless of language?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, textview

In my application I use `Grid` control to show some text and I face that problem when the text is Arabic (As Arabic text starts from right) it starts from the right of its area like is shown below:

[image: Unexpected output]

When I set the `XAlign` attribute to `"End"` it made the English text start from right.

I want it starts from `Left` regardless of the nature of the language like is shown in below image, Is there a way to do that?

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After other some search and trials I used **custom render** for my `Label` which equivalent to `TextView` in Android and after tried some attributes like `android:textAlignment`. The only attribute worked for me and achieved my goal is `android:gravity` and here is its rendering code:

```
Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.Left;
```